# On textbox click ,show(pop up) a calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

I would like to know how can I implement a calendar when the textbox is clicked? 
Example: When I click a textbox , the calendar will pop up . 
Like this : [image]

I clicked the textbox and the calendar showed up.

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine that you want to do this entirely client side, using javascript/JQuery, rather than constantly round-tripping to the server, as there will be a lot of interactions.  The post should be tagged accordingly.  There are also several existing libraries or open source projects providing code for filling in a calendar using javascript/JQuery.  I'd look to use one of them, rather than writing your own from scratch.  It'll be quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AJAX Control Toolkit has this exact functionality in it.

[ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit Calendar Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Cross Browser Implementation with jQuery UI Datepicker:

[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div style="display: none;" class="demo-description">
<p>The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.  Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay.  Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is shown as the input's value.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like jQuery UI maybe:

http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: this should really be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Why?  It answers the question - it's the solution I would use if needing to create a calendar dropdown like this.

Comment: @Paddy - the OP would still have to do a bit of digging and drilling down to get to the resource s/he needs. If you're posting a link make it specific.

Comment: Telling someone just what technology to use (when that isn't the question itself) seems rather...lacking...in an answer.  He's asking how to do it, not what language to code it in.  If you included the jquery event he'll want to use, and the code to show a popup/div in the event handler then sure.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and easiest way is to use JQuery or other Javascript framework.

There's a demo here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

you may try the juice [datepicker](http://juiceui.com/controls/datepicker) control